# What kind of grammatical construction is "He looked up at me, his harsh face expressionless"?

Tags: sentence-structure, absolute-clauses

What kind of grammatical construction is this? Is it a participle?

> He looked up at me, his harsh face expressionless.

Comment: If you mean _expressionless_, it's an adjective (describing how his face looked at that moment).

Comment: I'm not too sure, so this is a comment rather than an answer, but I would say that the phrase following the comma is an _adverbial phrase_ modifying 'looked'. After all it gives more information about the way he looked at you.

Comment: In English, a participle can be [defined](https://www.lexico.com/definition/participle) as "A word formed from a verb (e.g. *going, gone, being, been*) and used as an adjective (e.g. **working** woman, **burnt** toast) or a noun (e.g. good **breeding**)." None of the words in the sentence fit that. Questions such as this are best asked on ELL, I think.

Comment: If you're asking about "his harsh face expressionless", then the answer is that it's an adjunct, more specifically it's the verbless analogue of  the 'absolute' clause "his harsh face being expressionless".

Comment: One treatment which uses the term 'absolute construction' in a broader sense than some might like is found at [Thirsty, we drank.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/254228/thirsty-we-drank/254245#254245) '*Its hair in glorious disarray, the horse raced along the beach*.' is the example closest in form to your sentence, though it postposes the independent clause.

Comment: I wouldn't say that "Thirsty, we drank" was an absolute construction. "Thirsty" is not a verbless clause but an AdjP functioning as a predicative adjunct -- an adjunct because (here) it is a supplement attached to a main clause, and predicative because it refers to a predicand, i.e. the subject "we". Compare the predicative complement in "We were thirsty".